# Lenovo Legion 5 touchpad

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have just bought a new Lenovo Legion 5-15ARH05.

I have a problem with the touchpad. It seems that it's recognized by the system,
however, I cannot move with the cursor. I found out that the left click and the right click works just fine.

I am using 5.8.0-050800-generic kernel and Synaptics package.

This is my xinput

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Consumer Control  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Mouse               id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Touchpad            id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Keyboard  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8910) Wireless Radio Control    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and by listing props I get

```
$ xinput --list-props 17
Device 'MSFT0001:00 06CB:7F28 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (274): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (275):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (276):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (277):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (300):  48, 1176, 43, 761
    Synaptics Finger (301): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (302):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (303):   64
    Synaptics Tap Durations (304):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (305):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (306):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (307):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (308):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (309): 29, 29
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (310): 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (311):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (312): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.136612, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (313):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (314):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (315):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (316): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (317):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (318): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (319):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (320): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (321):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (322): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (323):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (324): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (325):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (326): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (327):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (328):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (329):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (330):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (331): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (332):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (333):  612, 0, 659, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (334): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (262):    1739, 32552
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event18"
```

The touchpad itself works in windows and when I disable hid-multitouch in Linux I can
get it working, but the cursor is moving in absolute coordinates so it's unusable.

If someone has an idea how to solve it I would really appreciate it.
On the internet I found some threads describing a similar problem, but
they don't talk about how the clicking is working and other stuff.
One lead might be that supposedly from kernel 5.4 it stopped working,
however, I cannot test it.

I am not able to boot 5.3. But I booted 5.0 and it did not work.

Comment: I suspect we need to wait for the kernel to catch up.  Some useful discussion here (https://www.linux.org/threads/lenovo-legion-5-touchpad.29536/).  It’s the same numbers in the device name as some Elan touchpads, but no elan modules are loaded on my system.  Will update if I discover anything new.

Answer (score 0):

did you try libsynaptics?
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics
I'm no expert but these drivers are not maintained anymore and sometimes provide people with better trackpad support still

Answer (score 0):

Partially answering the question. There is a fix but it is not in the kernel yet.

On https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1887190 there is a discussion about this issue and as for now, it looks like it can be patched with the zip from #217 with an approach explained in #211.

For me, this solved the issue and hopefully, this will be fixed on the kernel level in the upcoming versions.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using Ubuntu 18.04

- Install

  ```
  sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04
  ```

> HWE - Hardware Enablement
>
> In simple words, is like a bleeding edge package for newer devices

I have the same laptop and I didn't need to blacklist anything after.

Comment: Is it working with ubuntu 20.04. I am going to buy the model that's why asking