# WiFi, Touchpad, Brightness not working on Lenovo Legion 5 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, brightness

I recently got a Lenovo Legion 5 laptop and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Unfortunately, the WiFi, touchpad, and brightness do not work. I have tried using multiple articles without success:

- [Wifi not working on Lenovo Legion Y520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006217/wifi-not-working-on-lenovo-legion-y520)
- [Lenovo Legion 5 touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253830/lenovo-legion-5-touchpad)

Comment: I would burn ubuntu 20.04 onto a usb stick and boot off that LiveUSB to see if your machine runs OK with 20.04 and if yes then reassess going to 20.04 instead of 16.04

Comment: You didn't say which 16.04 you installed, ie. I'm asking if you used media that defaults to the GA kernel & stack, ie. very early 2016 software stack, or used media that uses the HWE kernel & stack meaning you'll get a later stack at most as modern as early 2018. The later stack has a greater chance, personally I'd opt for software that doesn't EOL in a few months as per Scott's prior comment.